# Give any example of the scp -S option funcionality

Tags: scp

What is the purpose of this function?

How can I use it to execute a command when using `scp`?

Example:

```
machine01~$ scp -S 'echo "command" #' -P 2222 me-jhon@machine02.org:/tmp/file *
```

I want to execute the `echo "command"` in my local machine (`machine01`). not `machine02`

I am glad for any answers.

Answer (score 4):

This is not for executing commands. As `scp`'s man states:

```
 -S program
         Name of program to use for the encrypted connection.  The program
         must understand ssh(1) options.
```

For executing commands use `ssh`. `scp` is a copy command based on `ssh`.

To execute commands on the local machine you don't need neither `scp` nor `ssh`.